# PostgreSQL geometry type invalid

Tags: postgresql, geometry, line

I'm trying to create some tables on PostgreSQL with a Geometry field. For the Polygon and Point types it works but when I want to create a Line  o LSEG type I get an error.

If I do:

```
.....
geometry_field geometry(Polygon, 25829),

or

geometry_field geometry(Point, 25829),
.....
```

it works and the table it's created but when I try:

```
.....
geometry_field geometry(Line, 25829),

or

geometry_field geometry(LSEG, 25829),
.....
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  Invalid geometry type modifier: line or lseg
```

Looking at the [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-geometric.html) the type exists so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Where is my mistake?

Edit:

I'm using a legacy system whith PostgreSQL 8.4 and PostGIS 1.5

Comment: It looks like you're mixing PostGIS and native geometry syntax. Please [edit] the question to specify the exact version of PostgreSQL and PostGIS software in use.

Comment: The link you have put is to Postgres geometry types, not Postgis ones,, which can be Point, Linestring, Polygon (or their multi versions) or geometry (a mixture of anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For line in postgis native will be Linestring

Comment: This answer is correct, but would be more useful if you listed all the valid types and gave a link.

Comment: I found this in the documentation: http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/javadoc/org/postgis/PointComposedGeom.html